# I am trying to get inverse of a matrix from a file in python, but the format is in string and even after changing it into float I am unable to do it

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, file-handling

I am trying to write a code which reads this file and gives the inverse of square root of each term in a matrix. This is the file I am using:

```
1.659999999999999963e-04
3.970000000000000005e-04
-8.014499999999999402e-02
-2.274299999999999933e-02
-7.559999999999999880e-03
-3.156229999999999869e-01
5.650100000000000261e-02
2.350100000000000106e-02
-4.383999999999999876e-03
-4.878299999999999997e-02
1.207599999999999993e-02
-5.254199999999999843e-02
1.123500000000000019e-02
1.614240000000000119e-01
1.954900000000000040e-02
-2.614100000000000104e-02
1.534899999999999980e-02
5.446000000000000320e-03
-6.210299999999999848e-02
-9.615000000000000283e-03
1.687800000000000064e-02
6.460999999999999729e-03
-9.490999999999999437e-03
1.676700000000000065e-02
-2.308000000000000156e-03
-1.412399999999999940e-02
8.978899999999999382e-02
1.848960000000000048e-01
5.956000000000000356e-03
-5.592300000000000049e-02
1.114599999999999966e-02
-5.689600000000000213e-02
-6.731000000000000004e-03
2.572999999999999940e-02
1.512000000000000106e-03
-3.237999999999999993e-03
-4.068999999999999700e-03
-1.234000000000000071e-03
2.378109999999999946e-01
-1.128000000000000096e-03
-3.534999999999999948e-03
-4.550000000000000008e-04
1.479999999999999925e-04
5.220000000000000031e-04
3.718099999999999877e-02
1.104580000000000006e-01
1.965000000000000167e-03
4.266999999999999960e-03
-5.140999999999999737e-03
1.648640000000000105e-01
1.776220000000000021e-01
1.922000000000000097e-03
3.250600000000000017e-02
4.402899999999999869e-02
-8.430999999999999259e-03
4.409999999999999858e-04
1.389999999999999905e-04
1.374209999999999876e-01
-2.431860000000000133e-01
-1.727000000000000019e-03
-2.280000000000000126e-04
8.100000000000000375e-05
-7.480999999999999803e-03
8.000000000000000654e-05
-3.939999999999999817e-04
1.441000000000000007e-03
-7.290000000000000473e-04
-3.663000000000000284e-02
-1.657999999999999969e-03
-8.369999999999999619e-04
-6.904999999999999680e-03
1.593100000000000072e-02
-3.393000000000000183e-03
1.495999999999999934e-03
-7.368999999999999682e-03
1.436199999999999977e-02
-1.319700000000000040e-02
-4.557000000000000287e-03
8.123700000000000365e-02
2.447399999999999923e-02
-1.295199999999999997e-02
-8.722100000000000686e-02
-5.232999999999999804e-03
-1.255940000000000112e-01
1.291999999999999963e-03
-1.382999999999999898e-03
4.989999999999999644e-03
1.508000000000000009e-03
2.304399999999999851e-02
2.819400000000000031e-02
3.119999999999999944e-04
-8.781999999999999876e-03
6.794500000000000539e-02
6.198999999999999649e-03
-2.058879999999999877e-01
9.219999999999999680e-04
-1.618800000000000100e-02
-3.415860000000000007e-01
-1.660999999999999933e-03
-4.889999999999999599e-04
1.759999999999999954e-04
-3.763999999999999985e-03
-6.566600000000000215e-02
-7.680000000000000195e-04
-1.231799999999999978e-01
7.047999999999999578e-03
1.425000000000000051e-02
-2.900799999999999906e-02
1.187499999999999944e-01
-1.449199999999999933e-01
-1.106999999999999911e-03
-1.557999999999999923e-03
-2.236999999999999839e-03
-7.270699999999999386e-02
-5.140000000000000254e-04
2.246999999999999865e-03
-1.778949999999999976e-01
1.669599999999999904e-02
-1.277799999999999943e-02
-2.379040000000000044e-01
-2.207999999999999893e-03
1.925000000000000062e-03
7.750100000000000044e-02
-5.004100000000000215e-02
1.704999999999999918e-03
3.272400000000000309e-02
1.957499999999999865e-02
-1.514620000000000133e-01
-3.288999999999999823e-03
-3.605699999999999877e-02
3.648999999999999900e-03
3.459799999999999681e-02
-1.859999999999999945e-04
3.300000000000000253e-05
3.000000000000000076e-06
9.999999999999999547e-07
4.800000000000000122e-05
1.361999999999999929e-03
-6.057300000000000184e-02
5.689999999999999529e-04
-5.000000000000000409e-06
2.984699999999999853e-02
6.999999999999999387e-05
4.600000000000000004e-05
-1.294499999999999991e-02
-2.318000000000000182e-03
-0.000000000000000000e+00
1.858200000000000129e-01
-5.969959999999999711e-01
6.000000000000000152e-06
```

The code I have tried to write is this:

```
from ast import Num
from cmath import sqrt

import math
import numpy as np
from numpy import append
f1= open('diagonal.txt', 'r')

k=f1.readlines()

#def mkstr(s):
   # str1=" "
   # return (str1.join(s))

#print(float(mkstr(k)))

#for j in f1:
#inverse_root(j) 
#def mkstr2():
   # f1=open("diagonal.txt", "r")
   # k=f1.readlines()
   # fl=[float(item) for item in k]
   # inverse_root(fl)

#for j in mkstr2():
    #inverse_root(j) 

f=[float(x) for x in k]
sa=np.array(f)
ca=sa.astype(np.float)
def inverse_root(j):
    return [1/(sqrt(j))]
j=[inverse_root(ca)]
```

I am getting the output like this:

```
DeprecationWarning: `np.float` is a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`. To silence this warning, use `float` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here.
Deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
  ca=sa.astype(np.float)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gian-2018/prateek/python/read_file/27/5/rmwpd.py", line 34, in <module>
    j=[inverse_root(ca)]
  File "/home/gian-2018/prateek/python/read_file/27/5/rmwpd.py", line 33, in inverse_root
    return [1/(sqrt(j))]
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

So to get inverse of sqrt for each term from the matrix file: I tried to convert the list of these strings into float list, but even after I get error for trying to get list of these numbers into the formula of inverse sqrt instead of using a real number.
Now I am trying to create the inverse formula suitable for an array which means creating a new array which converts each term in the previous matrix into their inverse sqrt and saves the value into the new array.

By any way possible please either tell me how to convert this list into real numbers or convert each term of this matrix into its inverse sqrt and save it into new matrix.
Or just tell me how to implement this task in any way possible if you have understood it.

Comment: `cmath.sqrt` only works with numbers - or a single element array that can be turned into one.  You must be giving it an array :(   Why are you using `cmath` and `math` functions?  Aren't the `numpy` equivalents good enough for you?

Comment: ok let me try that